# How to automatically link bundle to xcframework

Tags: bundle, xcframework

I used `pod lib create` to create a private library to package an xcframework. I need to package the bundle resources into the xcframework, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. If the static library is changed to a dynamic library, the resource bundle will be automatically linked